# Query works with MySQLi Query, but not with with a prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Most of the queries I have on my PHP pages do not accept user input, so I haven't used prepared statements for any of them, just the standard `MySQLi->query` method. For the search function, I need to sanitize my inputs.

My search function, however, does not work. No error gets thrown, every method returns `true`, but `$res->num_rows` is always 0. The query gets executed succesfully from phpMyAdmin.

```
function searchArticles($query, $page, $othpage){
    $db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pswd, $db_name);
    if($db){
        $q = "SELECT id, title, summary, timestamp, author, urltitle
            FROM articles
            WHERE title LIKE ? OR summary LIKE ? OR content LIKE ? OR tags LIKE ?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($q);
        $query = '\'%'.$query.'%\'';
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $query, $query, $query, $query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $res = $stmt->get_result();

        $textfill = "";
        $total_rows = $res->num_rows;
        if($total_rows > 0){
            while($a = $res->fetch_assoc()){
                /* Doing stuff */
            }
        }
        else {
            $textfill .= "No results found";
        }
        $db->close();

        /* Other stuff */
        return $textfill;
    }
    return "";
}
```

I quickly bodged it to run with the classic `query` and it works flawlessly.

```
function searchArticles($query, $page, $othpage){
    $db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pswd, $db_name);
    if($db){
        $q = "SELECT id, title, summary, timestamp, author, urltitle
            FROM articles
            WHERE title LIKE ? OR summary LIKE ? OR content LIKE ? OR tags LIKE ?";
        $query = '\'%'.$query.'%\'';
        $newq = str_replace('?', $query, $q);
        $res = $db->query($newq);

        $textfill = "";
        $total_rows = $res->num_rows;
        if($total_rows > 0){
            while($a = $res->fetch_assoc()){
                /* Doing stuff */
            }
        }
        else {
            $textfill .= "No results found";
        }
        $db->close();

        /* Other stuff */
        return $textfill;
    }
    return "";
}
```

What is wrong with my code? Why does it work the with "unsecure" method and it does not with the prepared statement?

Comment: You do not need all of the escaping you're doing here `'\'%'.$query.'%\'';` It should just be `'%'.$query.'%'`

Comment: Why you're searching for the quoted patterns?

Comment: Yeah, nvm... I did 30 more seconds of rubber duck debugging and I noticed the problem.